# Spring-MVC scheduling task and updating jsp based view in real-time

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, real-time

What I want to achieve is to use Spring-MVC `@Scheduled` annotation to download csv files, save them to the hard disk and then insert them into the database using `JDBCTemplate`. I would like to update JSP based view in real-time when Java method managed to insert contents of a csv file to the database.
Basically, my web page should be displaying:

> Started 13:30:52!
>  13:32:30 Inserted file1.csv into database!
>   13:34:38 Inserted file2.csv into database!
>  13:36:22 Inserted
>   file3.csv into database!
>  13:36:23 Completed! You don't have more
>   files to download!

I imagine my Java code should have some method like `afterInsertedSuccessfully()` which sets success message into the model if no database errors present and the JSP can load this message from model. How can I load this message then in real-time? Is it mandatory to use Jquery (Javascript) or can JSP view handle it internally? Why I don't like JQuery approach is this approach uses timer to poll updates. I want my solution to be more like event-driven.

Comment: There are basically two ways for an HTML page to be modified asynchronously: either it polls the server, or you use a web socket connection. HTTP doesn't allow for a server to push data to a client.

Comment: Yes, that right, u have to use websockets or polls to push data from webserver to client, and if u dont want to use jquery then I suggest u to use websockets as they are implemented in html 5 only and you can directly send data from java code to websockets from afterInsertedSuccessfully()

Comment: When my download method uses @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000) do I encounter blocking IO? Does it influence my web page? Does visitor's browser freeze or something like that?

Comment: You might make it event-driven if you create custom event which you can handle or use already existing solutions with worker threads.